# itertools count() resets with multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, counter, python-itertools, pool

I don't understand why the id counter of a class using `itertools`'s `count()` would reset after using a `multiprocessing` `Pool`. What should I change in the code below so that *object id = 1 / worker id = 0* is printed after the first `Pool` worker is done?

```
from itertools import count
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Obj(object):
    _ids = count()

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = next(Obj._ids)

def print_ids(worker):
    obj = Obj()
    print(f"object id = {obj.id} / worker id = {worker}")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    worker = "None"
    print_ids(worker)

    with Pool(processes=5) as pool:
        pool.map(print_ids, range(5))
```

output:

```
object id = 0 / worker id = None
object id = 0 / worker id = 0        <<< obj.id resets here
object id = 1 / worker id = 1
object id = 2 / worker id = 2
object id = 3 / worker id = 3
object id = 4 / worker id = 4
```

Comment: Each process is going to have its own, entirely independent copy of `class Obj`, and therefore also of the `Counter` that it holds.  The only reason that you got any increments of the ID at all is that `print_ids` finished so quickly, that the next invocation went to the same worker process, rather than another process in your pool.  You either need to assign distinct IDs from the main process, or use one of the various mechanisms provided by `multiprocessing` to share a variable between processes.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. What method would you suggest for sharing a counter variable between processes? I've tried many different methods but always get errors such as `daemonic processes are not allowed to have children` or `can't pickle _thread.lock objects`.